# Big O of searching and comparing contents of binary search trees

Tags: java, big-o, binary-search-tree

I have a program that takes two binary search trees, tree1 and tree2, that are filled with strings. The program does an inorder traversal of tree1 and for each string in tree1, it searches for that string in tree2. I think that searching for each value from tree1 in tree2 has a complexity of O(logn) and the traversal to go through every value in tree1 has a complexity of O(n). Does this mean that the entire process is O(nlogn), n for traversing tree1 to get each value and logn to find that value in tree2? I'm not very good at understanding big-O notation, so any help or explanation is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is :

you have a sorted array t1 :

```
var t1 = ['1','2','3','4']
```

and you have a tree that is both sorted and as flat as possible given a maximum value of 2 children per node ( binary search tree )

```
var t2 = '1' -> '2' -> '4'
             -> '3'
```

Now for each element in t1 you are going to search for that element in t2.  Just as you were thinking - this means to do a logN operation n times which gives you nlogn total computation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is `O(n.logn)` if both your trees have n elements and the second is [optimised for searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree). If the number of elements differs, and tree 1 has n elements and tree 2 m, then it is of course `O(n.logm)`.

To understand it: You should count the number of operations in the algorithm in terms of n. Finding an element in tree 2 will take a maximum of `logn` comparisons. Going through tree 1 will take n elements to look at. Since you do the finding for each element in tree 1, you multiply the number of operations and arrive at a maximum of `n.logn` operations.

You might remark that a comparison consists of addressing 2 elements, or that comparisons are more time-consuming, so that in fact we should say `log(2n)` (or some other factor), but that is just a constant factor, independent of n, and is therefore filtered out in the `O()` notation.

Saying that an algorithm is `O(n.logn)` means that one can find a constant C such that for all n the algorithm will complete in at most `C.n.longn` time (worst case), and there is not a more limiting boundary, like, for instance, `O(n.log(logn))`.

So, yes, it is `O(n.logn)`.

Comment: f it is a traditional binary tree, your conclusion is correct if and only if the tree was randomly constructed and no deletions are done.
And the conclusion is in probabilistic terms

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *probabilistic* here, because the big O notation in the context of algorithms provides an upper bound (worst case).

Comment: Probabilistic in the sense that O(log n) is the expectation for the number of nodes visited during a search. But this is only valid if the tree was randomly constructed. If this condition is not meet, then O(n log n) is not an upper bound, but O(n^2). Consider, for example, that n-1 nodes have only a child; in this case the bound is O(n). If on the binary tree  an equilibrium condition applies, an AVL for example, then it would be possible a bound of O(n log n), because the height is bounded to O(log n). But the author of post did  not say with which kind of binary tree he deals

Comment: Of course, I took it for granted that the second tree was optimised for optimal searching (I added this remark in my answer yesterday). I now understand that *probabilistic* was concerning the distribution of nodes. I agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order transversal on tree1 is O(n) where n is the total number of nodes in tree1. On the other hand, the (binary) search on tree2 is O(log m) where m is the number of nodes in tree2. So the total complexity of your algorithm would be O(n logm).

If the size of tree1 is equals to the size of tree2, then yes the complexity is O(n logn).